# Tool to saturate NFS traffic

Tags: nfs

Does anyone know of a tool I can use to saturate NFS traffic?  The reason is I'm seeing some Cisco switch Output errors that I believe is caused by high NFS traffic and trying to replicate the problem.

Is there a tool I can use to really bring up the NFS throughput between 2 servers?  Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

a simple file copy operation, running in a few instances should be enough. if you want even more, I'd run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/nfs_mount/filename bs=$blocksize count=$amountOfBlocks`
Knowing the NFS params should provide the blocksize to be used, you can play with those.

To really saturate it, I'd run a few of those dd's simultaneously